# Is the identity theorem for holomorphic functions being correctly applied here in the proof of this trivial claim?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $\pi(x)$ be the number of primes not exceeding $x$ and $Li(x) = pv (\int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log t})$. Consider the prime zeta function.

**(Trivial) Claim:** For $\Re(s)=\sigma>1/2$, one has

$$s\int_{1}^{\infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1}  \mathrm{d}x-\log((s-1)\zeta(s))=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\log \zeta(ms)$$.

**Proof:** Consider the prime zeta function $$\sum_{p} p^{-s} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\log \zeta(ms)$$ for $\Re(s)=\sigma>1$, where $\mu$ and $\zeta$ denote the Mobius and Riemann zeta functions, respectively. Li(x) is the Cauchy principal value for $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log t}$ for $x>1$.

Applying partial summation to the left-hand side sum over primes $p$ together with the identity $\int_{1}^{\infty} s Li(x)x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x=-\log(s-1)$ for $\sigma>1$ yields

$$s\int_{1}^{\infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1}  \mathrm{d}x-\log((s-1)\zeta(s))=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\log \zeta(ms)$$ for $\sigma>1$. Let $\Pi(x)=\pi(x)+\frac{1}{2}\pi(x^{1/2})+\frac{1}{3}\pi(x^{1/3}) + \cdots$. Since $\log \zeta(s)=s \int_{1}^{\infty} \Pi(x)x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x$ for $\sigma>1$, it follows that hence $\log((s-1)\zeta(s))=s \int_{1}^{\infty} (\Pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x$. Thus the LHS of the preceding equation is identical to $s\int_{1}^{\infty} (\pi(x) - \Pi(x))x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x$. Note that $|\pi(x)-\Pi(x)| \ll x^{1/2}$. For $\sigma>1/2$ and all $m\geq 2$, we also have $\zeta(ms)=1+2^{-ms}+3^{-ms}+...$ thus $|\mu(m)\log \zeta(ms) | \ll 2^{-m \sigma}$ for $\sigma>1/2$ and all $m\geq 2$. These bounds imply that both sides of the preceding equation are analytic everywhere in the larger plane $\sigma>1/2$. Thus the desired result follows (?) by the identity theorem for holomorhic functions ?

**Remark:** The above claim is being said to be trivial, in the sense that it doesn't seem to lead to any significant result. For one, it certainly doesn't imply the RH, at lest on its own, since the convergence of the RHS of the above identity for $\Re(s)>1/2$ doesn't rule out the possibility of some zero to the right of the critical line.

Comment: Replace $\pi(x)-Li(x)$ by $x^\rho$ and $\log \zeta(s)(s-1)$ by $\frac1{s-\rho}$ to see why you are missing something completely trivial.

Comment: @reuns, if i correctly understood your comment, it seems you're saying that the validity of the equation is conditional on the RH. I don't think this is necessarily true, since both $s\int_{1}^{\infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1} dx$ and $\log ((s-1)\zeta(s))$ can individually have singularities at $s=\rho$, whilst $s\int_{1}^{\infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1} dx-\log((s-1)\zeta(s))$ is well-defined around $s=\rho$. Recall that if $f(s)$ is singular and $g(s)$ is also singular, it doesn't necessarily mean that $f(s)-g(s)$ is singular. This is the same reason why the equality doesn't entail the RH.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_1^\infty x^\rho x^{-s-1}dx-\frac1{s-\rho}$$ converges  only for $\Re(s)> \rho$ and in there it vanishes. This doesn't tell us anything about $\rho$. This is exactly the same situation as in your questions

Comment: Can you be more specific ? Which ''one of my questions'' are you referring to ? Clearly, my only question is on the application of the identity theorem.

Comment: I told you : replace $\pi(x)-Li(x)$ by $x^\rho$ and $\log((s-1)\zeta(s))-\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\log \zeta(ms)$ by $1/(s-\rho)$, this is exactly the same situation except now each term is easily understood. I'm swearing, trust me, anything about $\pi(x)-Li(x)$ can be translated in term of $x^\rho$ so do it, translate your claims in term of $x^\rho$ and see if they are valid

Comment: Are you talking about the expression of $\pi(x)-Li(x)$ in terms of the zeros ? Then you want to be more specific. $\pi(x)-Li(x)=Li(x^{\rho})+\cdots$.

Comment: Can you be more specific please ? Exactly which part of the reasoning are you referring to ?

Comment: Can you please apply your reasoning, all your reasoning, to $\int_1^\infty x^\rho x^{-s-1}dx-\frac1{s-\rho}=0$ and show what you get or where you are stuck ?

Comment: I'm not trying to be insulting with you : I swear, trust me, that the answer to your questions is obvious once you forget $\log\zeta(s)$ and look instead at obvious (counter) examples like $\int_1^\infty x^\rho x^{-s-1}dx-\frac1{s-\rho}=0$

Comment: Your counter-example is trivially flawed: The reasoning doesn't apply for $\Re(s)<\Re(\rho)$, since the integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{\rho} x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x$ is undefined  for such $s$ whereas $\frac{1}{s-\rho}$ is well defined, thus there is no cancellation of singularities hence the equality $\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{\rho} x^{-s-1} -\frac{1}{s-\rho}=0$ can nolonger be possible.

Comment: It works exactly the same way for your identities. The integral converges only for $\Re(s) > \Re(\rho)$, beyond there it is only an identity about the analytic continuation of it

Comment: Clearly it's not the same. In my question, there is a possible cancelation of singularities for $\Re(s) \in (1/2, 1)$ at a possible zero of zeta on this region. I mean, both the integral and $\log((s-1)\zeta(s))$ can be singular at some point $s$ with $\Re(s)\in (1/2, 1)$, but the LHS of the equation can still be well-defined around that point. I had already explained this.